# Adding the FB Graph API OAuth token in AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm quite new to the world of programming, and having learned `HTML`, `CSS` and `JQuery`, I've decided to take up the task of building a  website which displays some info of public FB pages.

I was exploring the [FB Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), and want to use the access token in my ajax call to pull info from public fb pages.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/xyzzzz', function(fbResult) {

        $.each(fbResult.data, function() {
            $('<div class="pic"> </div>').append(

            //the operations will go here

            ).appendTo(body);//This could be a sidebar or a specific id as well

        });

    });

});
```

What would be the format of the URL in  `$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/xyzzzz', function(fbResult) {`

if I wanted to access, say, posts or photos of published, public FB pages from the Graph API?

I tried going through the documentation, and also some tutorial videos on Youtube. I'm grateful for any and all help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the FB [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) reference. If you know the photo-id and you have an Access Token then:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{photo-id}?oauth_token={accessToken}
```

Dont have an access token? Then try [oEmbed Facebook Content](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed-endpoints):

```
 https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F{page-name}%2Fphotos%2F{photo-id}%2F
```